# Java socket receiving file and then send response back to client

Tags: java, wireshark, serversocket

I have problem when I establish socket server, and client could send file to me and I could receive that.But when I tried to send ACK message to client, they can not receive that.

```
            dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            File file = new File("D:/socket/files/");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdir();
            }
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
            inputByte = new byte[1024];
            System.out.println("Start to receive file");
            while ((length = dis.read(inputByte, 0, inputByte.length)) > -1) {
                String s = new String(inputByte,0,length);
                fos.write(inputByte, 0, length);
                fos.flush();
            }
            System.out.println("File Received Location: " + filePath);
            OutputStream out = client.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(out);
            pw.write("hello");
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
```

This is my server receive and send message code. I used wireshark to find that after client send data to me, I will automatically send [ACK] message back without any content, then client send [FIN,ACK] to me, I could send two message back, one is [ACK] and another is [PSH,ACK]. "hello" message is inside [PSH,ACK] packet. I think the reason is when client send[FIN,ACK] to me, they already closed connection. Is there anyway I can add message in the first [ACK] packet I send back to client?[wireshark-capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Laja7.png)

Comment: FIN means exactly that the peer closed the connection. There is no client code here. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. But why would you do that ? Your client is sending a data, and once acknowledged (ACK) it is closing the connection. It wouldn't even read the data the server is sending. The real question is, does the client expect data ? It seems that no.

Comment: client said they are expecting the ACK back, but my ACK answer is out of sequence